# Is there a function to add to the bottom of a c++ stack?

Tags: c++

I could always use an array and write an algorithm for pushing items to the top but a stack would probably be more efficient and simpler to use later. I've searched for this function and couldn't find one.

Comment: What about using `std::deque` ?

Comment: You can't push to the bottom of a stack by the definition of that data structure. Use a double ended queue instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::stack` is a *container adapter*, not a container itself. That means it simply enforces a stack interface (which by definition only offers push and pop to the top of the stack) over the top of a user specified underlying container that provides `push_back()`, `pop_back()` and `back()` functions. By default `std::stack` uses `std::deque` as its underlying container but `std::vector` and `std::list` are standard containers that also meet the requirements (and `std::vector` is probably a better choice in most cases).

If you want to be able to push to the other end of the stack then just directly use a container that supports that efficiently - `std::deque` is likely your best choice.

Comment: `std::deque` was something i hadn't heard of before this only `std::stack`. `std::deque` is probably what i will use as i just need a stack that i can add to the bottom of every once in a while

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), which provides both [`std::deque::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back) and [`std::deque::push_front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_front) methods for pushing elements to the "top" and "bottom" of the data structure, respectively, in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stack` is a FILO data container, full stop. You can add to the back and then you can remove from the back. If you need to do anything else, then you need to use a container that isn't `std::stack`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using wrong container for what you want to achieve. deque seems to be a better fit.